# How do I find the ContextMenuStrip that a ToolStripMenuItem belongs to?

Tags: winforms, contextmenu

I have a `ContextMenuStrip` where one of the items has a `DropDownItems` property that is a collection of dynamically added `ToolStripMenuItem` objects. When I handle the sub-item `Click` event, the sender is of type `ToolStripMenuItem`, but its `Owner` is a `ToolStripDropDownMenu`. I can't find how to determine the 'host' ContextMenuStrip from this. It has no `Owner` property of its own, and `Parent` returns null.

When I use this adaptation of the code posted by @Steve below:

```
Dim dropDownItem = DirectCast(sender, ToolStripDropDownItem)
Dim menu As ContextMenuStrip = DirectCast((((dropDownItem.DropDown).OwnerItem).OwnerItem).Owner, ContextMenuStrip)
Dim grid = menu.SourceControl
```

then `menu.SourceControl` is `Nothing`, yet when I handle a top level, i.e. non-dropdown menu item's click like this

```
Dim item As ToolStripMenuItem = DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)
Dim strip As ContextMenuStrip = DirectCast(item.Owner, ContextMenuStrip)
Dim grid As DataGridView = DirectCast(strip.SourceControl, DataGridView)
```

then I get the grid I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to reach the ContextMenuStrip object from inside an Click event of a ToolStripMenuItem belonging to a ToolStripDropDownMenu.

If this is the case then

```
   private void TestToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripDropDownItem x = sender as ToolStripDropDownItem;
        if (x != null)
        {
            ContextMenuStrip k = (((x.DropDown).OwnerItem).OwnerItem).Owner as ContextMenuStrip;
            k.ForeColor = Color.Red; // as an example.
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works 98%, but for some reason, the `SourceControl` property of `k` is null, where it isn't null when I handle a click event of a non-dropdown context menu item, i.e. a top level item.